# Bing Map Silverlight Control Architecture Diagram in ASP.NET

Tags: bing-maps

I am planning to use Bing Map for a store locator system. I will be using Bing Map Silverlight control for this in an ASP.NET website. The website has a 3 tier architecure.

Could you please tell me where I can find some architecture diagrams that explains the bing silverlight control in a web based system (with ASP.NET)

Note: The store locator application must be able to collect store's cordinate values from database and show it in the graph - as expected in a store locator system.

Request: Could you please add a ASP.NET tag into this question, if you have rights in this forum?

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 1):

I have written an Article in my Forum, I use Silverlight to Display the Store locations on the Map. I have a mark on each store on the map. you can view it here 
[How to use Telerik’s Map Control in Silverlight 4](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1165-how-to-use-teleriks-map-control-in-silverlight-4-.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

All the Bing Maps for SL control is a Silverlight-based control that is hosted within a webpage, i.e. in your case an .aspx page.

Generally these architectures follow something like this:

PC Client (Silverlight running) -- Web Service (on web server) -- ASP.NET Page (on web server) -- Database (on database server)

This is a physical diagram.  I did not include the logical diagram which would include your client model and server model of your entities, DAL, BLL, etc.

Hope this helps.